# Smallest Stack Frame Size

Tags: linux, assembly, stack, i386

I'm currently doing the Capture-the-Flag event by Stripe (you should check it out if you haven't seen it yet). The event requires you to look at disassembled executables a lot, and my knowledge of asm is rusty.

I keep seeing the constant `0x18` show up as some sort of minimum stack size. For instance, in a function that allocates a char[1024] array and calls the function strcpy(), the assembly looks like this:

```
8048484:    55                      push   %ebp
8048485:    89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
8048487:    81 ec 18 04 00 00       sub    $0x418,%esp
804848d:    8b 45 08                mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
8048490:    89 44 24 04             mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
8048494:    8d 85 f8 fb ff ff       lea    -0x408(%ebp),%eax
804849a:    89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
804849d:    e8 e6 fe ff ff          call   8048388 <strcpy@plt>
80484a2:    c9                      leave  
80484a3:    c3                      ret
```

Why is the extra space needed?

Comment: The compiler is enforcing a 16 byte alignment.

Comment: Wait, wouldn't it then have to be `0x420`? `0x418` isn't divisible by 16.

Comment: Before a function call, the stack is 16 byte aligned. When you perform the call, a 4 byte return address is pushed. The first thing the called function does is push `ebp`, for another 4 bytes. Therefore, the compiler has to subtract 8 to align it, plus a multiple of 16 for any data used.